# How to diiferentiate Empty and Null Value from Select Statement [Sql Query] to get result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

This is my XML String

```
'<DocumentElement>
  <XMLExport>
    <VehicleNo>TR45TA1234</VehicleNo>          --- > VEHICLE PRESENT IN DB [ALLOW]
  </XMLExport>
  <XMLExport>
    <VehicleNo/>                               ---> VEHICLE NO IS EMPTY [Allow]
  </XMLExport>
  <XMLExport>
    <VehicleNo>TR45TA123412121</VehicleNo>     ---> VEHICLE NOT IN DB  [DO NOT ALLOW]
  </XMLExport>
</DocumentElement>'
```

I am reading Excel file into Datatable and then to XML String.I need result like

```
1st Part : If Vehicle No. present in **DB** Then **Allow** To Upload
2nd Part : If Vehicle No. Column is EMPTY Then **Allow** 
3rd Part : If Vehicle No is not Empty and Not present in **DB** Then DO NOT Allow
```

**This is my Query**

```
create table #UplaodXMLDemo
(
 VehicleNo varchar(20),
) 

INSERT INTO #UplaodXMLDemo
SELECT 
ExportPass.EP.value('VehicleNo[1]', 'VARCHAR(15)')as VehicleNo,
FROM  @XMLString.nodes('/DocumentElement/XMLExport')ExportPass(EP)  


  SELECT  VehicleNo,VH_SRNO,
  (
   select Top 1 case when ltrim(rtrim(ISNULL(CDX_MST_VEHICLE.VH_NUMBER,'')))  is not null then 'YES' else 'NO' End As IsVehicleExist   from CDX_MST_VEHICLE where CDX_MST_VEHICLE.VH_NUMBER =UD.VehicleNo
 ) as IsVehicleExist

FROM #UplaodXMLDemo UD 
left join CDX_MST_VEHICLE ON CDX_MST_VEHICLE.VH_NUMBER =UD.VehicleNo
```

How do , I get above results.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an empty `VehicleNo` to the table you `Left Join`:

```
Declare @XMLString xml = '<DocumentElement>
  <XMLExport>
    <VehicleNo>TR45TA1234</VehicleNo>
  </XMLExport>
  <XMLExport>
    <VehicleNo/>
  </XMLExport>
  <XMLExport>
    <VehicleNo>TR45TA123412121</VehicleNo>
  </XMLExport>
  <XMLExport>
  </XMLExport>
</DocumentElement>';

With UplaodXMLDemo As (
    SELECT 
        ExportPass.EP.value('VehicleNo[1]', 'VARCHAR(15)') as VehicleNo
    FROM @XMLString.nodes('/DocumentElement/XMLExport')ExportPass(EP)
), CDX_MST_VEHICLE As (
    SELECT 'TR45TA1234' As VH_NUMBER
)
Select UplaodXMLDemo.*
    , CASE WHEN Allowed.VehicleNo IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS Decision
From UplaodXMLDemo
Left Join (
    Select VH_NUMBER As VehicleNo
    From CDX_MST_VEHICLE
    Union Select '' --< Add empty value to allow it too
) Allowed On Allowed.VehicleNo = COALESCE(UplaodXMLDemo.VehicleNo, '')
```

Also might be worth taking into consideration NULL `VehicleNo` test case.